# Error in Python's TimeSynth for generating Autoregressive Process

Tags: python, numpy, time-series

I am trying to create a AR(2) using python's TimeSynth. However, I am getting the following error. I know that it is because the code is trying to cram some inconsistent
array into a numpy array element but I am not sure where the root cause is.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import timesynth as ts

# Initializing TimeSampler
time_sampler = ts.TimeSampler(stop_time=20)
# Sampling irregular time samples (timestamps)
irregular_time_samples = time_sampler.sample_regular_time(num_points=500)

# Initializing AR(2) model
ar_p = ts.signals.AutoRegressive(ar_param=[1.5, -0.75])
ar_p_series = ts.TimeSeries(signal_generator=ar_p)
samples, signals, errors = ar_p_series.sample(irregular_time_samples)

# Plotting the sampled time series
plt.plot(regular_time_samples, samples, marker='o', markersize=4)
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.ylabel('Value')
plt.title('Autoregressive process - Second order')
plt.show()
```

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. The requested array has an inhomogeneous shape after 1 dimensions. The detected shape was (2,) + inhomogeneous part.
```